# Function in postgresql wit ref cursor

Tags: function, postgresql

Im trying to migrate an oracle procedure to a postgresql function. Here's the function in postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tibrptsassure.call_reasons(i_start_date date, i_end_date date, i_intnbr character varying, i_intmodnbr character varying, oc_ref_cursor refcursor)
  RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
      OPEN oc_ref_cursor FOR 
      SELECT COUNT(1),INTERACTION_NBR,INTERACTION_ID,INTERACTION_MODULE_NBR,CREATED_BY
      FROM tibrptsassure.d_tcare_interaction , tibrptsassure.d_calendar d
      WHERE INTERACTION_ID = i_intnbr
      AND INTERACTION_MODULE_NBR = i_intmodnbr AND INTERACTION_DATE BETWEEN i_start_date AND i_end_date
      AND INTERACTION_DATE BETWEEN d.week_start_date AND d.week_end_date
      GROUP BY INTERACTION_NBR;
return oc_ref_cursor;  
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

But, while executing this function, I dint get any output. Got a message: Query result with 1 row discarded.

```
begin;
select tibrptsassure.sampleproc_call('10-Feb-2010','31-Dec-2013','30681','Bypass_IDV','funccursor');
FETCH ALL IN "funccursor" ;
COMMIT;
```

Whats wrong in the query?

Comment: You operate with ` tibrptsassure.sampleproc_call()`, yet you keep that one as secret as your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: I used tibrptsassure.call_reasons() only. Im using PgAdmin version 1.14.1.

Comment: pgAdmin is only the GUI. The version of PostgreSQL is relevant. Run `SELECT version()` against the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with pgAdmin and multi-statement transactions.  Use psql instead.

Basically pgAdmin doesn't know what to do at that point and so it discards the row and you can't with cursors outside such an environment.

Comment: Thanks Erwin Brandstetter and Chris Travers.